# JBPM Business Central Admin icon (Gear Icon) not shown - JBPM 7.56.0

Tags: authentication, authorization, admin, jbpm, kie-workbench

I have configured JBPM-7.56.0 to use DB authentication. Now I can login with the users defined in the DB. But when I login, I cannot see the Admin (gear) icon now, even if I login with a user with admin privileges.

[image: Default property file based authentication]
[image: DB based authentication]

I tried a couple of different configurations. But still could not resolve it.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Below is one of the user/role details I tried with.

User table entry:
[image: User table]

UserGroup table entries:
[image: UserGroup table]

Comment: Do you have server.log traces? It seems the assigned group is not admin

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, Thank you for your support. I cleared the DB and configurations and did it all again from the beginning. Now it is working. But I could not figure out the exact reason. I assigned the same set of groups as above to krisv and now it is working. Thanks again.